# How to use List<List<int>> as parameter in method?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio

I haven't found any description or explanation how to insert List< List of int> as parameter with values in method nor to Console.WriteLine()

I have tried some variants, but non of them seems to work. So I'm trying to find help here.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Result.ListManipulation()));
        //I want to insert 3 Lists and manipulate with them inside the method
        //List<int>{11, 2, 4 };
        //List<int>{4, 5, 6};
        //List<int>{10, 8, -12};
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
        class Result
        {
            public static int ListManipulation(List<List<int>> arr)
            { 
                //Manipulation with those 3 Lists
                return 0;
           }
        }
```

If You have some easy to use explanation, I'm open for Your knowledge!

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you have control over `ListManipulation`, consider using the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword for a parameter that takes a variable number of arguments. For example, if you use `public static int ListManipulation(List<int> lists)`, you can call it like this `Result.ListManipulation(list1, list2, ...);` or `Result.ListManipulation(new List<int> {11, 2, 4}, new List<int> {4, 5, 6}, ...);`.

Comment: It is just some (totally normal) datatype you hve created. Why would there extra documentation?? Note however, that, since List<T> is a reference type you need to be very clear about what you want to manipulate: The original or real copies (best created with a `ToList()` call on the lists..)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should do is to create and fill the *nested* `List<List<int>>`:

```
...
// You should create a nested List - new List<List<int>>()...
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>() {
  // ... and fill it line by line 
  new List<int>() { 11, 2,   4 },
  new List<int>() {  4, 5,   6 },
  new List<int>() { 10, 8, -12 },
}; 

int result = ListManipulation(myList);

...
```

Comment: Note that target-type `new` in C# 9 allows you to eliminate all types for the `new()` expressions, since the type of `myList` is enough to infer them.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: you are quite right, but when answering such questions (very basic ones) I tried to put code as *simple* as I can even if it's a bit *wordy* (it's possible to put `var myList` or write just `new` as you have mentioned)

Comment: Sure, the "you" in my comment was also a generic "you" to anyone reading the answer who might be in a position to use it.